# Do I need to update my CLR version for .NET Framework 4.7.2?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, clr, .net-framework-version, .net-4.7.2

I understand the difference between the .NET Framework and the Runtime (CLR). However, the versioning does puzzle me a little.

For the past 8 years or so, the .NET Framework has increased in versioning, yet the CLR version seems to have stayed at 4.0. Have no changes been made to the CLR?

Does this also mean that the on the web server, to run an application built using 4.7.2, as long as the Runtime version 4.0 is installed, then it would still run?

I can see on the [Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download) that there's a separate download for the Runtime package.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each version has added features and possibly contains CLR changes. If you use any of these features then you cannot run on a smaller version.

The .NET version system is pretty messy. You cannot gather much from the version integers themselves. But there is no need. What counts is merely the succession of versions.

There are three version epochs: 1.x, 2-3.x, 4.x. Assemblies must be compiled for one of them and can only be loaded there. Only 4.x matters now to most people.

You can target downlevel versions in Visual Studio. The compiler will then only let you use APIs that are available in that version. That way you can make sure that you can run on downlevel version numbers. This is not 100% failsafe since there have been behavior changes. But compatibility generally is extremely high with .NET.

For applications that you deploy on your own infrastructure I highly recommend synchronizing all developer and production machines to one .NET version if feasible. That way you will not experience compatibility issues and you can ignore the entire question of versions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @usr. Yeah it's the versioning which is leading to my confusion. So I guess it's best to ignore the runtime versions and just always grab the version of the runtime which is shipped with the newer framework version?

Comment: The two are bundled. You have no choice in that. You can only chose to install something higher than what you app needs. That's OK in most cases.

Comment: I understand they are bundled in the Framework download, but you can get the runtime as a separate download. On your web server you would only want the runtime, not the entire framework - that is my understanding anyway.

Comment: @TophatGordon - it's not runtime vs. framework. It's runtime vs. SDK/Dev pack. They runtime does include the framework.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am using Framework and SDK/Dev pack interchangeably here (from .NET Framework days). But my understand is still that it is just the runtime which is needed on a web server to run a .NET Core app.

Comment: @TophatGordon .NET Core and .NET Framework are two distinct products with different ways of acquiring them among other differences.
When you talk about .NET Core, then the runtime part is all you need to run your application -- and there is a special installer for that.

Comment: @ Alex Ghiondea - MSFT Yes I was getting my terminology mixed up. When I said Framework, I really meant the full dev pack - the bits needs for building and running an application.I was confused by @Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment about the runtime including the framework.

Comment: Yes, because up until your previous comment, we seemed to be talking about .NET Framework, not Core. And there the "runtime" package includes all of the framework assemblies, installed under `c:\windows\microsoft.net\v<version>`